# How to create one suite inside another suite in Microsoft test manager by using api

Tags: c#, api, tfs, mtm

here is the first step

```
IStaticTestSuite testSuite = _teamProject.TestSuites.CreateStatic();
// create an empty test suite below
IStaticTestSuite mtmTestSuite = _teamProject.TestSuites.CreateStatic();
```

I  would like to add `mtmTestSuite` inside `testsuite` as we can do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code:

```
ITestPlanCollection plans = testproject.TestPlans.Query("Select * From TestPlan");
            var p = plans.Where(pp => pp.Name == "Plan1").First();
            IStaticTestSuite newSuite = testproject.TestSuites.CreateStatic();
            newSuite.Title = "Acceptance Tests";
            IStaticTestSuite pSuite = p.RootSuite.Entries.Where(s => s.Title == "WindowsFormDemoTest").First().TestSuite as IStaticTestSuite;
            pSuite.Entries.Add(newSuite);
           // p.RootSuite.Entries.Add(newSuite);
            p.Save();
```

More ways you can refer the part of *'Add New TFS Test Suite*' from this link: [Manage TFS Test Suites C# Code](http://automatetheplanet.com/manage-tfs-test-suites-csharp-code/)

Comment: Thank you for your help! but your logic suppose that i have only one test suite--> (First()) in my plan. what can i do if i have a many test suites and want to create subtestsuite(test suite inside another)  for only  some of them.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating the testSuite and mtmTestSuite in the same time, you just need to add one line code to add mtmTestSuite into testSuite after testSuite has been created and added to Test Plan/Suite :

```
testSuite.Entries.Add(mtmTestSuite);
```

If the testSuite is already exist, then you need to get the testSuite first and then add mtmTestSuite into it. For example:

```
    IStaticTestSuite testSuite = itmtp.TestSuites.CreateStatic();
    foreach (IStaticTestSuite ts in itmtp.TestSuites.Query("Select * From TestSuite"))
    {
        if (ts.Id == 103)//Get the test suite by ID
        {
            testSuite = ts;
        }
    }
    IStaticTestSuite mtmTestSuite = itmtp.TestSuites.CreateStatic();
    mtmTestSuite.Title = "Title";
    testSuite.Entries.Add(mtmTestSuite);
```